# PhpStorm Version 2020.1: Meaning of dots on file icon symbol

Tags: icons, phpstorm, symbols

Can anyone explain to me what these two dots on some file icon symbols stand for in PhpStorm Version 2020.1? I could not find anything helpful in the documentation e.g.:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symbols.html

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This comes from Symfony plugin. [From v0.20.196 Changelog](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#020196):

> Provide custom Twig file overlay to indicate "extends" and attached controller template types

Those icons provide hints on what's inside the file (e.g. somehow similar to how PHP files are handled: separate icon for PHP Class, Trait, Abstract class, Exception etc).

- Red dot for "controller"
- Yellow dot for "extends"

You can check more here: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1485